# Power failure during upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 resulting to desktop not working

Tags: upgrade, dual-boot, 12.10, dist-upgrade

While upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 due to power failure, the desktop environment is not working. It shows 12.04 but no icons are there.

If I went through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> it went into terminal in which my login ID and password is not working.

How one can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you make the GRUB boot menu visible during boot? You can choose a "safe mode" from there. I believe you have to hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> during power up to enter the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your situation, did you reinstall 12.04 after the failed 12.04 to 12.10 upgrade?

I just installed 12.04 and have a desktop with invisible icons in the Unity Launcher.  Still trying to resolve the issue, seems to be something with Unity 3D / compiz.

As a work around, you can try Unity 2D.  At the login screen, right click the Ubuntu circle thing and select Ubuntu. Continue to login.